# Angularjs: Pagination in different route

Tags: angularjs, routes, pagination

I have been struggling with this issue for some time now. I have implemented pagination in my home page, Which works fine. I have a search input on my home page, Which returns products based on user search. In controller I am routing the data to different URLs and passing the data using $rootScope. That's working fine too. But the pagination breaks in second route, since my pagination functions were in home controller, I was unable to access those functions, even when delared with $rootScope or duplicating all functions doesn't work too. Also, the pagedItems is showing empty array in second route, even when declared with $rootScope. Below is sample plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/fIU2DZEVUc8HVUp7sgaF?p=preview

My Questions:

1. Where to write reusable functions in AngularJS and how to use them in my views.
2. What is the best way to implement this logic, assuming my approach to the problem is wrong.

The JSFiddle / Plunker example is much appreciated.

**Thanks in advance for any help!**

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Really appreciate it guys!

Answer (score 0):

In your link `search.html` is bound to `homeController` whereas you are specifying its controller as `fpctrl` in route settings. The best way to search is to pass the result as parameter to `search.html` and place search input box and button outside the `ng-view` in main page.

If you want to write resusable functions then you have to write them in factory or services.

Answer (score 0):

this would probably want be the strict answer to you questions. Still would you consider `$filter` functionality? For this, you need to change your text input as:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="product" ng-model="search">
```

then you could remove your search button. And add the `| filter:search` along with ng-repeat of your elements.

here is a bit complex but full example http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/

Comment: No @ysusuk. That Search button is to call service and get data. I will not have all the data with Initial load. Sorry if the example i showed is confusing.

Comment: yeah, sorry =) i wrongly understood that. How about that - to store your search results into a service along with your pagination functions:

Comment: and then inject it firstly into `home` view controller and then in `search` view controller. Service is angular singleton. the thing is that in your current configuration, when you specified homeController for both views, each will have different instances (and as @Kavitha K Gowd said you don't have `fpCtrl` at all). so routing defines which controller to use for which view

Comment: @ysusuk..I am trying to implement the same currently, But i don't have much experience in Angular/JavaScript in general. Can you please show a function and variable call from service..based on which i ll try to move my logic to service. Also, how to access those functions in my controller/view need to be checked from my end.

Comment: if you specified `ctrl` in `$routeProvider` you can avoid specifying it in `view.html`

Comment: Didn't understand your last comment. This is where i got stuck. plnkr.co/edit/4N9gQS?p=info

Comment: here is how i changed the `app.js` and `home.html` https://docs.google.com/document/d/16qXVK9d63q4pBVs4Y0cwjXAn9H4pNJu3X-0gjNk8-iE/pub

Comment: the basic idea is to move shared functionality into PaginationService. Then inject to controller and call from the view as `PaginationService.methodName()`. Or in controller create `$scope.methodName = PaginationService.methodName()` and invoke as usual.

Comment: I think that solves the issue @ysusuk. I will approve the answer once i verify it. I wish i could vote up for the effort. But i didn't have enough points. Sorry :(